# Every so often BLE rssi weakens for about 2 minutes Android Beacon Libary

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, altbeacon

Every so often the rssi is not getting any stronger than -55. It can go weaker than this value but cannot go to -30 even if the phone is right next to the beacon. This lasts for about 2 minutes before it goes back to normal.

I am using the android beacon libary and currently am only using foreground scanning.

Comment: My app is constanly on and not scanning in the background

Comment: What is the phone model?  Is WiFi on?  Can you reproduce with WiFi off?  Can you reproduce on a different phone?

Answer (score 0):

RSSI is notoriously unreliable. Bluetooth uses the 2.4 GHz ISM band, which it has to share with dozens of other device types that can emit RF in this band. Your problem might even be caused by a neighbour running a creaky old microwave oven that's not properly shielded anymore.